# Compare string lines in 2 files

Tags: python

I have logs outputs with thousands of lines for users and emails, that are generated by an application that assigns licenses, to use some resources, to those users.

Now the scenario is that, I export those txt lists every week and I want to compare them and get new users being licensed so I can make up a report.

Say, I have one of those files I exported last week and want to compare it with the one I exported this week and output the new users that got licensed within that period of time.

What I'm thinking is to grab line 1 of file A, and compare it to ALL lines in file B.

Then get line 2 of file A and compare it to ALL lines of file B.

And so on.

```
f1 = open("logs/older_output.txt", "r")
f2 = open("logs/newer_output.txt", "r")

for line1 in f1:
    line1 = line1[0:50]
    for line2 in f2:
        line2 = line2[0:50]
        if line1 == line2:
            print("match: ", line1)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Now, that snippet will output matches between lines, say, line 1=1 and lines 2=2.

But is it really necessary to compare each line of A against each line of B?
Isn't there any other simpler/efficient method to achieve this?

Comment: Will it be possible for you to extract the user names from any given log file? If yes, then you can make a separate file which only contains the names of users, after extracting the user names from the log file. So keeping that in mind, for every log file that you have, can then have a user name file for it. This file can be then used to compare your other weekly generated user name files.

Comment: There's an error in your snippet. If you want to compare each line of f1 to each line of f2 you have to reset the f2 file pointer to the beginning of the file as the last line of the outer loop: `f2.seek(0)`. Otherwise you will only pass through each file once.

Comment: Is your question how to do this efficiently?

Comment: question is how can i compare 2 almost identical txt files and get the changes

Comment: Your code has a bug. It would be extremely inefficient to read all of `f2` from disk again for each line from `f1`; but you would need to close and repen , or rewind, `f2` after each iteration of the outer loop for this to work. Your current code will simply find that `f2` is already exhausted on the second and subsequent lines from `f1`.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are very similar (e.g. file b is just file a plus some extra lines) you could compare them with the `diff` command line tool, which is made for this:

```
diff logs/older_output.txt logs/newer_output.txt
```

Or if `newer_output.txt` contains everything in `older_output.txt` plus some extra lines, you could just jump straight to those extra lines in Python:

```
with open('logs/older_output.txt') as f1, open('logs/newer_output.txt') as f2:
    old_n_lines = len(list(f1))
    new_lines = list(f2)[old_n_lines:]
```

Or, if every line in `newer_output.txt` could potentially be anywhere in `older_output.txt`, then you can cross-search much faster if you put the lines in `older_output.txt` in a `set` before comparing. You can search the entire set instantaneously no matter how many items are in the set, which is much faster than testing against every line in `old_output.txt` individually. This would do that:

```
with open('logs/older_output.txt') as f1, open('logs/newer_output.txt') as f2:
    old_lines = set(f1)
    new_lines = [line for line in f2 if line not in old_lines]
```

If you only want to match on part of the line, you could amend these to only work with that part.

Answer (score 0):

The Pandas library allows you to do this relatively easily. I'm assuming that each line has only a single email address on it. If you have multiple fields, you'll have to share a sample file for a more specific solution.

```
import pandas as pd

file_a = pd.read_csv('logs/newer_output.txt',header=None,names=['email'],sep=',')
file_b = pd.read_csv('logs/older_output.txt',header=None,names=['email'],sep=',')

new_emails = file_a.loc[~file_a.iloc[:,0].isin(file_b.iloc[:,0])].iloc[:,0].to_list()
```

If the columns in the file are separated by anything other than columns, you'll need to update the "sep=','" part to tab, space or whatever is the delimiter.

Comment: files contains columns for, email addresses, type of license, date and time and 365 organization user id from, that is why trying to do something like "line1 = line1[0:50]" so i can capture just the email addresses